# (c++) get data after executing mysql query group_concat

Tags: c++, mysql, get, group-concat

i have a question. i have a complex query and it contains `group_concat`.

```
MYSQL_RES* res = GetDBManager()->Query("select ls.time, count(ws.id) , group_concat(wc.id) , group_concat(ws.SIGNAL_STRENGTH) , ul.LATITUDE , ul.LONGITUDE , ul.ALTITUDE  from user_location_scan ls, wifi_scan ws, wifi_cell wc, user_location ul where ls.id = ws.user_scan and ws.wifi_cell = wc.id and ls.time = ul.time group by ls.id order by ls.id");
```

how can i assign the data in `group_concat` to a `struct` such as

```
struct {
        int APid;
        double rssi;
    }* sigstr;
```

i already tried a loop `for()` but it didn't work.

```
    while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) {
    int j = 0;
    inf.time.FromSQL(row[j++]);
    inf.numAP = atoi(row[j++]);
    for (int i = 0; i < inf.numAP; i++) {
        inf.sigstr[i].APid = atoi(row[j++]);
        inf.sigstr[i].rssi = atof(row[j++]);
    }
...
```

please help me.

UPDATE:
after some searching, i found that the data returned by `group_concat` actually cannot be assigned to an array. are there any ways to convert it?

Comment: Question is not clear, need more details

Comment: ok i added my query i used